# Can a CSS custom property contain more than one value to be referenced?

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

Let's say I want to create a series of class selector values that can be reused multiple times.

```
.shaded {
   background: black;
   color: grey;
}
```

I then want to use both of those selector values in something else within the CSS.

```
.box1 {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
.box2 {
   width: 75px;
   height: 75px;
}
.box3 {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
}
```

I want box1, box2, and box3 to have the values of .shaded. I don't want to have type

```
background: black;
color: grey;
```

for box1, box2 and box3 each time. Is there a way to accomplish this using CSS custom properties e.g. "var(--shaded)"? If not CSS custom properties, what *can* I use? I have to avoid JS and things like it at all costs as I'm working in a sandboxed environment that doesn't allow access/use of JS etc. It's just Bootstrap and SCSS.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't apply multiple classes within the same HTML tag? Like: `<div class="shaded box1">Shaded box #1</div>` this will give the same result.

Comment: I’m trying to keep my HTML as clean as possible and also got a bit overly excited about native CSS variables and wanted to see if I could do this entirely inside the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "extend" capability of SASS (SCSS) helps you.

just use

```
@extend .shaded
```

where you want.

you should write your CSS code in a .scss format file to be able.

also the link below help you

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend

Comment: So only SASS (and similar pre-processors) allows this as of the date of this question? No native custom property selector way?

Comment: exactly. only pre-processors

Comment: your welcome. did my answer helped you? if so, please mark it as best answer :)

Comment: I had, originally, as it came first out of the other “also-right” answers, but the check mark didn’t stick. I fixed that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let assume you have .shaded selector.

```
.shaded {
    background: black;
    color: grey;
}
```

In Sass you can import any class definition into another selector like below

````
.box1 {
    @extend .shaded;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.box2 {
    @extend .shaded;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
.box3 {
    @extend .shaded;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```
````